# How to send a message to all worker role instances?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I was using AzureQueue to communicate between roles.  My messages like "GoToMaintenanceMode", "StopSendingEmails", "DoNotAcceptRequests" etc. But I realized that, it won't work for my scenario when I have multiple instances due to queue message will shows up only 1 instance at a time.

So my question is beside the options below is there an elegant way to handle this issue something like Role.AllInstances.Run() etc.?

**the method I'm using it right now:**
instance peeks the message, adds it's own instance id to the message and puts it back to the queue, and does not peek the message if it contains it's own instance id.

*P.S. I do not want to implement TCP listener, asking for native solution if there is one.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use Windows Azure Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions instead of queues. They support multicasting (i.e. multiple receivers).

A short how-to guide can be found here

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/

Basically, your queue would become a Topic all your instances would become Subscriber to the Topic.

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't the answer I was expecting but it is a great idea to handle it.  But prefer something more native, so will mark as an answer if there is no alternative to this one.  Again, thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Just curious what "more native" means. You have a variable number of instances, and you want to broadcast a message to all of them. You have Azure storage queues (non-optimal), service bus queues (with pub/sub, optimal, "native" to Azure), tcp ports (very quick, easy to enumerate in RoleInstance, supported trivially and "native" to Windows). I'm not sure what other answers you'll get at this point, aside from maybe rows in a SQL table or Azure Table storage with commands? Again, variable instance count, so you'll have to account for that.

Comment: @DavidMakogon as I stated in the question, I'm looking for something like Role.AllInstances.Run if there is one.  I will definitely use Service Bus instead of Queue.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that you need one subscription for every instance, otherwise each message will be delivered to one or more but most likely not all instances.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not want TCP listener option or Service bus option. How about extending your same idea with multiple queues. Instance1 will read from Queue1 and Instance2 will read from Queue2 and so on. The only thing you need to handle is the number of queues and simultaneous adding of queue messages to all the queues.

Comment: @cilerler exactly the same architecture as explained above. Thanks for the link

Comment: Is there a way to send the same message to multiple queues, or do I have to manually call .Send() on both QueueClients? Just wondering if there is a more efficient way? It would be nice if AutoForward would let you store-and-forward to a second source for example...